# How do I fix an InvalidArgument error when trying to train a TensorFlow model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm training a machine learning model for a cat and dog image classification project and I seem to have encountered an error when attempting to train the model which I think could be due to the type of input data I'm passing or flaws in the model's structure.

Creating directory, preprocessing,and dataset variables:

```
# Get project files
!wget https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/project-data/cats-and-dogs/cats_and_dogs.zip
!unzip cats_and_dogs.zip
PATH = 'cats_and_dogs'
train_dir = os.path.join(PATH, 'train')
validation_dir = os.path.join(PATH, 'validation')
test_dir = os.path.join(PATH, 'test')
# Get number of files in each directory. The train and validation directories
# each have the subdirecories "dogs" and "cats".
total_train = sum([len(files) for r, d, files in os.walk(train_dir)])
total_val = sum([len(files) for r, d, files in os.walk(validation_dir)])
total_test = len(os.listdir(test_dir))
# Variables for pre-processing and training.
batch_size = 128
epochs = 15
IMG_HEIGHT = 150
IMG_WIDTH = 150

train_image_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=0.00392156862)
validation_image_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=0.00392156862)
test_image_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=0.00392156862)

train_data_gen = train_image_generator.flow_from_directory(directory=train_dir, target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT,IMG_WIDTH),class_mode='binary',batch_size=batch_size,shuffle=True,color_mode='rgb')
val_data_gen = validation_image_generator.flow_from_directory(directory=validation_dir, target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT,IMG_WIDTH),class_mode='binary',batch_size=batch_size,shuffle=True,color_mode='rgb')
test_data_gen = test_image_generator.flow_from_directory(directory=PATH,target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT,IMG_WIDTH),classes=['test'],class_mode='input',batch_size=batch_size,shuffle=False,color_mode='rgb')
```

Building and training the model:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=(32,32,3)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer="Adam",loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
#training
history = model.fit(train_data_gen,steps_per_epoch=round(total_train)//batch_size,epochs=epochs,batch_size=batch_size)
```

Error Screenshot:
[InvalidArgumentError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNCo4.png)

Any ideas on what could be causing the problem?

Comment: the error says 'incompatible shape', check your input, the input shape doesn't match the batch size

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please **re-read** [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as it would seem that you missed some crucial points the first time you read it, namely "***DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question*" (emphasis in the original).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your generators you specify IMG_HEIGHT = 150 and IMG_WIDTH = 150. However in your model you have the code

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=(32,32,3)))
```

change the input shape to (150, 150,3). As a side note you code

```
train_image_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=0.00392156862)
validation_image_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=0.00392156862)
test_image_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=0.00392156862)
```

since the are identical just use

```
gen=tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=0.00392156862)
```

then

```
train_data_gen = gen.flow_from_directory(directory=train_dir, target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT,IMG_WIDTH),class_mode='binary',batch_size=batch_size,shuffle=True,color_mode='rgb')
val_data_gen = gen.flow_from_directory(directory=validation_dir, target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT,IMG_WIDTH),class_mode='binary',batch_size=batch_size,shuffle=True,color_mode='rgb')
test_data_gen = gen.flow_from_directory(directory=PATH,target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT,IMG_WIDTH),classes=['test'],class_mode='input',batch_size=batch_size,shuffle=False,color_mode='rgb')
```

Also in model.fit since you are using generators you should not include the parameter batch_size as it is already specified within the generator. I also do not include the parameter steps_per_epoch. If you do not include it then model.fit will calculate it properly internally.

Comment: Thank you so much! All this time I was just trying out different values for the input shape and adding/removing layers hoping it would resolve my error.